# Indian English and with regard to Words usage

Tags: indian-english

When I am describing myself to the interviewer, should I say *I am post graduate* or *Post graduated*. Which one is the perfect ?

Comment: I do not know how those expressions would be received in India, but they would be viewed as very bad English in the US and, I suspect, in the UK. Is the implication here that Indian English has a standard that differs significantly from either standard British English or standard American English? Or, to put it a different way, can people from the UK or US even answer this question?

Answer (score -1):

You can say :

> I am a post graduate

or,

> I have a post graduation degree in (subject)

or

> I have done my post graduation in (subject)

In my opinion it is better to say the second one, i.e,**I have a post graduation degree in (subject)**, as it also gives you a chance to mention which subject you took in your post graduation.

Comment: No, you can't. At least not idiomatically. All three sentences should use [**postgraduate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/postgraduate).

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks for pointing out, I didn't know!! But the third one will sound weird with *postgraduate*, no? Maybe the natives don't speak like that, but see what I found : https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/post-graduation...

Comment: You are missing a point, of course I'm not talking about spelling here(nobody knows whether I'm giving a space or hyphen in in interview), I'm talking about the use. In UK/US, post graduation, as to mean the academic work or a degree is wrong english , but in South Asia (like India) IT IS used to mean academic work or degree. See the link I posted in the previous comment.

Comment: Countering those Oxford Dictionaries examples of *post-graduation* are their own examples of [*postgraduate*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/postgraduate). You'll see that Oxford has far more examples of *postgraduate* than they do of *post-graduating*.

Comment: Yes I've seen those

Comment: [Google Books NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=postgraduate+degree%2Cpost-graduation+degree%2Cpost+gradution+degree%2Cpostgraduation+degree&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpostgraduate%20degree%3B%2Cc0) only charts *postgraduate degree*. None of the other variations (*post-graduation degree*, *post graduation degree*, or *postgraduation degree*) appear at all.

Comment: See I am not trying to prove you wrong or anything, and I've clearly admitted that: I didn't know that it was wrong + native speakers don't use that term. As a native speaker you do know well.  What I'm trying to say is that, people in south Asia (like the op is Indian) use that term and Oxford Dictionary is the proof (to you guys its wrong I get that,I totally get that, so you'll not get other instances of the use, and I know that too.)